# how to build liburing

Tags: c++, linux

I am build liburing which is a user interface for io_uring features.
But when I run `./configure` it throws this error:

```sh
/tmp/fio-conf--21449-.c:2:10: fatal error: linux/time_types.h: No such file or directory
 #include <linux/time_types.h>
          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
```

but I found in

```sh
/usr/src/linux-headers-5.3.0-46-generic/include/uapi/linux$ ls time_types.h 
time_types.h
```

My kernal version is

```sh
uname -rs
Linux 5.3.0-46-generic
```

I'm sure that the 5.3 version is supporting io_uring (which has already been supported by 5.1)

so how to Update kernel/libc headers to support this?

Comment: It's probably looking in /usr/include/linux, not that folder. Can you check how /usr/include/linux is set up - is it a symlink to somewhere under /usr/src/linux-headers-* ? Which distribution is this?

Comment: `/usr/include/linux/time_types.h` : (Debian), Ubuntu → `linux-libc-dev`... and Fedora, RHEL, CentOS → `kernel-headers`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you have to clone the repo:

```
git clone https://github.com/axboe/liburing.git
```

Then you can build:

```
make -C ./liburing
```

After that, you can compile your `program.c` with liburing:

```
gcc program.c -o ./program -I./liburing/src/include/ -L./liburing/src/ -Wall -O2 -D_GNU_SOURCE -luring
```

Comment: The makefile runs ./configure though, and OP's problem is that ./configure doesn't work. So I don't think the make step here will work.

Comment: and was helpful.....